# Sequential select from list

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, sample

I have python list of say three number [0,1,2,3]

If i select 5 times then i should see 
0,1,2,3 then back 0  and so on . 
random.sample dsnt gurrantees  it will finish selecting all numbers from pool before repeating.
Shuffle also not so  useful

Comment: Please [edit] and tag a language ([tag:python]?).

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to include the code you have so far, and what issue it has.  But the usual method would be to have a shrinking array, so that only the numbers that are left are available for the next random selection.

Comment: What does "Shuffle also not so useful" mean? What is wrong with shuffling? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, random numbers do not guarantee that all numbers will be selected before repeating -- the numbers are random.  What you want is a shuffle.  You put the numbers you want in a list/array/etc: [0, 1, 2, 3].  Then you shuffle the list: [2, 3, 1, 0].  Now pick the numbers in order from the shuffled list.

Some languages have a built in `shuffle()` function.  Otherwise you can implement a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to do the same job.